# Fastest way to multiply and sum 4D array with 2D array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, linear-algebra, jax

Here's my problem. I have two matrices `A` and `B`, with complex entries, of dimensions `(n,n,m,m)` and `(n,n)` respectively.

Below is the operation I perform to get a matrix `C` -

```
C = np.sum(B[:,:,None,None]*A, axis=(0,1))
```

Computing the above once takes about 6-8 seconds. Since I have to compute many such `C`s, it takes a lot of time. Is there a faster way to do this? (I'm doing these using JAX NumPy on a multi-core CPU; normal NumPy takes even longer)

`n=77` and `m=512`, if you are wondering. I can parallelize as I'm working on a cluster, but the sheer size of the arrays consumes a lot of memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you want [`einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html):

```python
C = np.einsum('ijkl,ij->kl', A, B)
```

With numpy on a Colab CPU I get this:

```python
import numpy as np
x = np.random.rand(50, 50, 500, 500)
y = np.random.rand(50, 50)

def f1(x, y):
  return np.sum(y[:,:,None,None]*x, axis=(0,1))

def f2(x, y):
  return np.einsum('ijkl,ij->kl', x, y)

np.testing.assert_allclose(f1(x, y), f2(x, y))

%timeit f1(x, y)
# 1 loop, best of 5: 1.52 s per loop
%timeit f2(x, y)
# 1 loop, best of 5: 620 ms per loop
```